# $a_1 =2,$ and $a_n = 2^{a_{n-1}}$ and $b_1 = 3,$ and $b_n = 3^{b_{n-1}}.$ Find the least prime divisor of $a_{2014}-b_{2014}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_1 =2,$ and $a_n = 2^{a_{n-1}}$ for $n\geq1.$ Similarly let $b_1 = 3,$ and 
$b_n = 3^{b_{n-1}}$ for $n \geq 2.$ What is the least prime divisor of $a_{2014}-b_{2014}.$ I am unable to start this problem.

Comment: It consist in computing remainder of of a long tower of exponents of $2$ and the same for $3$ mod primes $2,3,5,7,11$. And checking if they are the same. You can skip $2$ and $3$. But don't skip $11$.

Comment: true or false the sequence a is always even and the sequence b is always odd ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee true

Comment: true or false that eliminates 2 from the possible prime factors ?

Comment: The general advice is that the 2014 may be a red herring (but some congruence it satisfies may conceivable come to the fore). Unless I made a mistake, it is easy to see the very simple pattern of both $a_n$ and $b_n$ modulo $5$ and $7$. And a bit more work also gives the same modulo $11$. And having done all that you can answer the question.

Comment: i solved the problem using casework for 5,7, and 11.

Comment: $a_{2014}-b_{2014}$ is negative... let's consider $b_{2014}-a_{2014}$  :)